# How can I install / upgrade WSL2 in my Windows 11 system?

Tags: windows, group-policy, bios, microsoft

I do not have access to `BIOS` in my system as it is a offical laptop.

I would like to install `WSL2` in my system. Somehow ***`WSL Update`*** didn't work for me.

```
PS C:\Users\anand.sathasivam> wsl.exe --update
Checking for updates.
The most recent version of Windows Subsystem for Linux is already installed.
PS C:\Users\anand.sathasivam> wsl -l -v
Windows Subsystem for Linux has no installed distributions.

Use 'wsl.exe --list --online' to list available distributions
and 'wsl.exe --install <Distro>' to install.

Distributions can also be installed by visiting the Microsoft Store:
https://aka.ms/wslstore
Error code: Wsl/WSL_E_DEFAULT_DISTRO_NOT_FOUND
```

I have installed Ubuntu from ***Microsoft Store***. When I open that it says,

```
Installing, this may take a few minutes...
WslRegisterDistribution failed with error: 0x80370102
Please enable the Virtual Machine Platform Windows feature and ensure virtualization is enabled in the BIOS.
For information please visit https://aka.ms/enablevirtualization
Press any key to continue...
```

Even `wsl.exe --install ubuntu` is failing.

```
PS C:\Users\anand.sathasivam> wsl.exe --install ubuntu
Installing: Ubuntu
Ubuntu has been installed.
Launching Ubuntu...
Installing, this may take a few minutes...
WslRegisterDistribution failed with error: 0x80370102
Please enable the Virtual Machine Platform Windows feature and ensure virtualization is enabled in the BIOS.
For information please visit https://aka.ms/enablevirtualization
Press any key to continue...
The installation process for distribution 'Ubuntu' failed with exit code: 1.
Error code: Wsl/InstallDistro/WSL_E_INSTALL_PROCESS_FAILED
```

So what I could do to solve this problem. I have concerned work above ***`WSL2`***, it is just not having `Ubuntu` in my `Windows 11` system over `WSL`. It is looks like my organization restricting me not to have anything like this over their ***`group policy`***. However I do not have access to `BIOS` I do have a ***administrative permission*** in my system, so I can run `gpedit.msc` and make the necessary changes.

Comment: `I do not have access to BIOS in my system` then you won't be able to enable virtualization ... the only solution is to enable virtualization. Someone at the "official" needs to help you ... note: group policy has naff all to do with accessing BIOS - what makes you think you can't access BIOS? is it password protected?

Comment: I do have access to my `BIOS`, I just checked pressing `F1`  while startup as mine is `Lenovo Thinkpad`. Consecutive to that, over `BitLocker`, by mistake, I had interrupted the booting sequence by pressing `Enter` and for now, my system is locked by `BitLocker` by showing `Recovery Key ID`—`{.....}` and allowing to press only `F1-F10`. Although I tried whatever was suggested over the console, I left with the only option to fall back with my ***IT Help Desk***. And I don't know whether I can alter my `BIOS` setup and I do have permission to do that.

Comment: that's a word salad - all I read was that you DO have access to BIOS ... so, make the required changes

Comment: Suggest me what changes which I have to do, I will do that on my `BIOS`,  when I am back to my system from my present `BitLocker` flaw, I'll let you know the model number once I am back to my `Lenovo Thinkpad` as it is not a typical `blue screen BIOS`. I will follow this link,- https://www.digitalcitizen.life/pc-laptop-model-windows-10/ to get my machine model number.

Comment: *ensure virtualization is enabled in the BIOS*

Comment: Now I have secured my system from `BitLocker` —`lockout` with my ***IT Help Desk*** team's help. And now I will try to enable `virtualization` in my `BIOS`. As I had agreed to give my `macine model number`, this is what I had found - `System SKU - LENOVO_MT_21D9_BU_Think_FM_ThinkPad P15v Gen 3`. I found this with the command `msinfo32`. The command `wmic csproduct get name` gives this `21D9S13700`. The `poweshell` cmdlet `Get-CimInstance -className Win32_ComputerSystem` gives the model number as `21D9S13700`, I mean the same. ***NOW***, let me try setting up `virtualization` in my `BIOS`

Comment: I was able to initialize `virtualization` on `BIOS` only when I had gone for `disk decryption` on `BitLocker`. Otherwise, `BitLocker` was not allowing us to enable  `virtualization` on `BIOS`

Comment: This is pure nonsense. Bitlocker has nothing to do with vt-d, but changing boot settings may cause the tpm to not unseal, and thus require the recovery key. I would suggest that you get help from your IT help desk to enable virtualization (or use WSL 1).

Comment: Here is my feed concerns to that, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77148122/is-virtualization-in-bios-must-be-updated-before-bitlocker-installation-and-conc I have done half of the work with the help of IT team. We weren't able to, till we turn the `disk decryption` done. Whatever you letting us to know, you may discuss it over the feed I have given. So it will be more meaningful.